# Updating database call without having to refresh page

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

A list of images (treasures) are displayed to the user, here the user will choose a single image which will be stored in the `Learner_treauser` table:

```
List<The_Factory_Chante.Models.Treasure> tresh;

using (The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext db2 = new The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext())
{

    string imageSource = "";

    tresh = db2.Treasures.ToList();

    foreach (var item in tresh)
    {
        if (item.itemImage != null)
        {
            string imageBase = Convert.ToBase64String(item.itemImage);
            imageSource = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase);
        }

        <img id="@item.treasureID" src="@imageSource" onclick="return MakeSure(@item.treasureID)" />
    }
}
```

The function called when an image is chosen. In this function the image is sent over to a webservice method to be saved to the database, and the page is reload for an update to take place:

```
function MakeSure(treshID) {

    var id = treshID
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../WebService.asmx/MakeSure",
        data: "{ 'id': '" + id + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }

    });
    window.location.reload();
};
```

However this is not very pleasant on the user's point of you. A better way would be to update without refreshing the page.

Here is the `Webservice` method that receives the chosen image id and stores it in the `Learner_Treasure` table.

```
public void MakeSure(int id)
{
   using (The_FactoryDBContext db = new The_FactoryDBContext())
   {
       Learner_Treasure learnTreasure = new Learner_Treasure();

       learnTreasure.dateCompleted = DateTime.Today;
       learnTreasure.learnerID = UserInfo.ID;
       learnTreasure.treasureID = id;

       db.Learner_Treasure.Add(learnTreasure);
       db.SaveChanges();

   }
```

Code to call `Learner_Treasure` table.

```
List<The_Factory_Chante.Models.Learner_Treasure> lern;
using (The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext db2 = new The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext())
{

    string imageSource = "";
    lern = db2.Learner_Treasure.ToList();
    if (lern != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in lern)
        {
            if (item.learnerID == UserInfo.ID)
            {
                byte[] bytes = db2.Treasures.FirstOrDefault(au => au.treasureID == item.treasureID).itemImage;
                string imageBase = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                imageSource = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase);
                <img id="@item.treasureID" src="@imageSource"/>
            }
        }
```

This code will show the user all the images they have chosen, however in if I take away `window.location.reload();` this code is only updated when the page reloads. Meaning that the user will not see their chosen image immediately after they have chosen it.

What I want to do is update the code that calls the `Learner_Table` without refreshing the page.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you don't want to refresh the page, delete the `window.location.reload();` Its unclear what you wanting to do in the ajax success callback - your returning data but never do anything with it

Comment: Your question is unclear, and you already have the update function in javascript. Just change whatever you have to change inside the `success` callback.

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali Your methods are not complete. What happens after `MakeSure`? Basically, what you need is to return something to your javascript function, and update the page accordingly. However, it's hard to get a complete picture with your code.

Comment: @AndreCalil I have added the missing method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way to approach this problem, you could use the [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) library.

This is what you would need to do:

**View**

```
// Include the SignalR Script
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>

// Provide a dynamic proxy for SignalR
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>

// Define hub connection(see below)
var hub = $.connection.yourHub;

// This is what the Hub will call (Clients.All.getImage(imageSource);)
hub.client.getImage = function (img) {
    var image = '<img id="' + img.treasureId + '" src="data:image/jpg;base64,' + img.image + '"';
    $(image).appendTo("body");
};

// Start the connection to the hub
// Once we have a connection then call the getLearnerTreasureItem on the Hub
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    var id = // whatever
    hub.server.getLearnerTreasureItem(id);
};
```

**Hub**

```
public class YourHub : Hub
{

    public void GetLearnerTreasureItem()
    {
        // All your code
        List<The_Factory_Chante.Models.Learner_Treasure> lern;
        using (The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext db2 = new The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext())
        {

         string imageSource = "";
         lern = db2.Learner_Treasure.ToList();
         if (lern != null)
         {
           foreach (var item in lern)
           {
             if (item.learnerID == UserInfo.ID)
             {
               byte[] bytes = db2.Treasures.FirstOrDefault(au => au.treasureID == item.treasureID).itemImage;
              string imageBase = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
              imageSource = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase);
            }
        }

        // This will now call the getImage function on your view.
        Clients.All.getImage(imageSource);
    }
}
```

Information on the [dynamic proxy](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#clientsetup)

Comment: My hub is complaining about the javascript embedded in this code. And the id passed in the methods parameters is never used.

Comment: Ok. Remove the id and remove the js code from the hub.

Comment: Can you also be a little more clear on how to link the view code with the rest of the code

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali Added in some code comments, if you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: very tempted! to mark this down, this is not addressing the problem, its a complete alternative.... not saying it wont work, but its missing the point!. Also as he is already struggling... introducing more complexity isn't a good way to go.., just my 2c

Comment: @Seabizkit On the first line of my answer 'There is another way to approach this problem'

Comment: @JamieR I get you, I was just considering the audience and complexity. Cleaner solution for now... would to be fix what he has, as its not bad from a design point.... then go into this when they understand the basics.... if that makes sense. Hence why i have not marked down, as that would not be right, but if this fixed what he had, I would mark up.;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `onclick` event handler here:

```
<img id="@item.treasureID" src="@imageSource" onclick="return MakeSure(@item.treasureID)" />
```

In the `MakeSure()` function you don't return anything. So you have two options, change your `MakeSure()` function to return false at the end, or change the onclick event to return false after the first function call in the image element, like this `onclick="MakeSure(@item.TreasureID); return false;"`

Also you will have to remove the `window.location.reload();` from the `MakeSure()` function.

*Side note, it seems you are mixing up your DbContext in your view, if that's the case, this is very bad practice. You should put your data access behind some sort of service layer that serves as a mediator between the view and your data.*

### Update

Ok after reading your question a few times I understand your problem
The problem is your second piece of code.

```
List<The_Factory_Chante.Models.Learner_Treasure> lern;
using (The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext db2 = new The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext())
{

    string imageSource = "";
    lern = db2.Learner_Treasure.ToList();
    if (lern != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in lern)
        {
            if (item.learnerID == UserInfo.ID)
            {
                byte[] bytes = db2.Treasures.FirstOrDefault(au => au.treasureID == item.treasureID).itemImage;
                string imageBase = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                imageSource = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase);
                <img id="@item.treasureID" src="@imageSource"/>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This calls the DB and gets a list of `Learner_Treasure` objects which you use to output  on view. Server side code gets executed once every page request, this is exactly what is happening. **It will not asynchronously update without a request to the server.**

You need to implement an ajax request to pull the latest Learner_Treasure list into the view. Again this comes down to the first side note I gave, the reason is because you are mixing your dbcontext with your view and expecting it to update on the fly. If you implement a layer which serves your view with the data (controller), you could call this asynchronously and have the page update without it reloading.

For instance you could write a call in your controller to get a single LearnerTreasure item in json.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetLearnerTreasureItem(int Id)
{
    using (The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext db2 = new The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext()) {
        learnerTreasureItem = db2.Learner_Treasure.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
        return Json(new { image = Convert.ToBase64String(learnerTreasureItem.itemImage), treasureId = learnerTreasureItem.TreasureID }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

And then call it with ajax in your view, like you did with the update.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: '/YOURCONTROLLERNAME/GetLearnerTreasureItem?id=1',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        //build image element
        var image = '<img id="' + data.treasureId + '" src="data:image/jpg;base64,' + data.image + '"';

        //add the image to where you need it.
        $(image).appendTo("body");
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
       alert("Error occurred while loading the image.");
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This does not refresh. It only just makes the page not to reload

Answer (score 0):

The way I approach this is by making a partial View for the code that needs to be refreshed

```
public PartialViewResult UserImages(your paramaters here)
{
   your code here
}
```

And then after successful $.ajax I refresh it

```
var id = treshID
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../../WebService.asmx/MakeSure",
                    data: "{ 'id': '" + id + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                         $.ajax({
                              url: "/UserImages",
                              data: your data model here,
                              success(function(html)){
                               $("#yourPartialViewWrapperHere").html(html));
                               }
                         });
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    }

                });
```

Comment: it is code which should fetch UserImages from the server, and send them as Model to your (newly created) partial view.
This is quite broad question, so I can't code it all for you, but am willing to help you debug any obstacles that you run into.

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali FYI this is the better answer of all the once posted so far... you need to understand this... so ask Zoran for more help if you not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Update in treasures images list

```
<img id="@item.treasureID" src="@imageSource" onclick="return MakeSure(this, @item.treasureID)" />
```

read that param in MakeSure method. also I just assume Learner_Treasure images listed in ul named 'ulLearnerTreasure'.

```
function MakeSure(sender,treshID) {
          var id = treshID;
          var imgSrc = $(sender).attr("src");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../../WebService.asmx/MakeSure",
                    data: "{ 'id': '" + id + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var li = '<li><img id ="'+ treshID +'"src="'+ imgSrc  +'" /></li>';
                        $("#ulLearnerTreasure").append(li);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }

                });

            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it using HtmlHelpers, like so: (as someone suggested, using db code directly is not a good practice, you need to change that.)

```
public static class HTMLHelpers
{
    public static IHtmlString TreasureImages(this HtmlHelper helper, List<The_Factory_Chante.Models.Learner_Treasure> lern)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext db2 = new The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext())
        {

            string imageSource = "";
            lern = db2.Learner_Treasure.ToList();
            if (lern != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in lern)
                {
                    if (item.learnerID == UserInfo.ID)
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = db2.Treasures.FirstOrDefault(au => au.treasureID == item.treasureID).itemImage;
                        string imageBase = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                        imageSource = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase);
                        sb.Append("<li><img id='@item.treasureID' src='@imageSource'/></li>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Placeholder for your images:

```
<ul id="TreaureImagesSection">
</ul>
```

In your cshtml page, load the list with this script, the first time or whenever you need the updated list

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: '/YOURCONTROLLER/TreasuresList',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {  // the data returned is List<The_Factory_Chante.Models.Learner_Treasure>
        $("#TreaureImagesSection").html('@Html.TreasureImages(data)');
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("Error occurred while loading the image.");
    }
});
</script>
```